# SQL Server - What is the RAISERROR substitution parameter for boolean/bit type?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, number-formatting, raiserror

I'd like to quickly dump some context into an error message including some boolean flags using the handy-dandy substitution parameters of `RAISERROR` such as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
(
    @param1 INT = 1,
    @param2 VARCHAR(255) = 'hello world'
) AS BEGIN
    ...
    RAISERROR('Inconsistent state occurred processing @param1=%d @param2=%s', 16, 1, @param1, @param2)
    ...
END
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) there is no type specification for `bit` type (boolean), but notes that

> These type specifications are based on the ones originally defined for the printf function in the C standard library.

And as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17307307/2799848) notes,

> ... since any integral type shorter than int is promoted to int when passed down to printf()s variadic arguments, you can use %d

But it does not work in SQL, as I get the following error (2748):

> Cannot specify bit data type (parameter ###) as a substitution parameter.

Am I forced to use a helper variable?

Thanks.

P.S. Using compatibility mode for 2008R2.

Comment: Can't you just CAST / CONVERT the BIT column/value to INT or TINYINT when calling?

Comment: You can't do any logic in the call to `RAISERROR`, everything must be a string literal or variable.
Converting to a `TINYINT`/other type implies using a  helper variable.

Comment: Good call.  How about something like this?  This uses formatmessage to make the error message itself, then pushes it into the RAISERROR call.  DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(1000) = FORMATMESSAGE('Error @param1=%d param2=%s', CAST(@param1 AS INT),@param2);
RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage,16,1);

Comment: ahhh, noticed you're using Compat for 2008R2.  Sorry, I'm out of gas here.